# Why is the second page of a fax truncated halfway using this code I use to send reports by fax?

Tags: delphi, fax

I am trying to automate faxing of reports from database in application developed using Delphi XE4 using Async Professional Components. Reports usually are multi-page, two to four pages including the cover page. I followed the guidelines of Async Professional components and was able to send faxes quickly. The first page goes fine and status update reports it is accepted at the receiving end. However, after the first page, the second page is truncated below the top third. The status shows progress of transfer only to hang at 100% and the transfer never appears to be completed. The status finally shows Fatal Timeout. Any guide up to where the issue is appreciated.

```
function TfrmFaxDispatch.SendFax: Boolean;
var
  Approutes: string;
  SchRec: TSearchRec;
  FaxPagesList: TStringList;
  accession: string;
  fax_number: string;
  I: Integer;

begin
  Approutes := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  FaxQry.Active := TRUE;

  if FaxQry.RecordCount > 0 then
  begin

    fax_number := FaxQry.FieldByName('fax_number').AsString;
    accession := FaxQry.FieldByName('accession_number').AsString;

    if Get_Case_Status(accession) = PRELIM then
      frmaedgeap.GenerateFinalDiagnosisReportFax(accession, TRUE, False)

    else
      frmaedgeap.GenerateFinalDiagnosisReportFax(accession, False, False);


    FaxPagesList := TStringList.Create;

    try
      FaxPagesList.Sorted := TRUE;
      FaxPagesList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

      if FindFirst(Approutes + 'APFReports\' + accession + '.*', faArchive,
        SchRec) = 0 then
      begin
        repeat
          FaxPagesList.Add(Approutes + 'APFReports\' + SchRec.Name);
        until FindNext(SchRec) <> 0;
        FindClose(SchRec);
      end;

      ApdSendFax1.PhoneNumber := fax_number;
      ApdSendFax1.HeaderLine := DateTimeToStr(now) +
        ' AEdge Diagnostic Lab  123-3456';
      ApdSendFax1.FaxFileList.Assign(FaxPagesList);

      if ApdSendFax1.FaxFileList.Count > 0 then
      begin
        ApdSendFax1.ConcatFaxes(Approutes + 'APFReports\OUTFAX.APF');
        ApdSendFax1.StartTransmit;
      end;

    finally
      FaxPagesList.Free;
    end;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: Have you contacted the component vendor support?

Comment: Thanks. I just found their contact page now. I will contact them. Their components are opensource.